# Objective-C - define an enum than can be dot called like ENUMTYPE.ENUMVAL

Tags: objective-c, enums, definition

I've read many things about enum types in objective-c, and I see there is many ways to define them. But I don't see the right way (if there is one) to define an enum that can be called with CARS.ROLLSROYCE and that cannot be used only with ROLLSROYCE in the code.

So I can define ROLLSROYCE in the CARS enum and also in the BEAUTIFULCARS enum.

Do you know the way to define such an enum ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to implement namespaces for your Enums in Objective-C.  What you're asking for is a lot of elbow grease in Objective-C.  You are probably best-off using C++ for this, since it is easy and afaik fully supported in any iOS or Cocoa application.  You'll have to rename the files that `#import` your C++ code to `.mm` files instead of `.m` files, and the C++ compiler can be trickier than the Objective-C one.  Going this route you'll create a header file like `Enums.h`.

```
//  Enums.h
namespace CARS
{
    enum CARS
    {
        ROLLSROYCE
    };
}
namespace BEAUTIFULCARS
{
    enum BEAUTIFULCARS
    {   
        ROLLSROYCE = 45
    };
}
```

And in your `.mm` sourcefile

```
#import "Enums.h"

-(void)printEnumvals
{
    NSLog(@"CARS %d BEAUTIFULCARS %d",
                     CARS::ROLLSROYCE,
            BEAUTIFULCARS::ROLLSROYCE);
}
```

If you want to avoid using C++ for this solution, there's a lot more elbow grease, bookkeeping, and opportunity for error.  You'll need a header and a source file for this.

```
// CARS.h
@interface BEAUTIFULCARS : NSObject
{
    enum
    {
        BEAUTIFULCARS_ROLLSROYCE = 45
    } BEAUTIFULCARS;
}
@end
@interface CARS : NSObject
{
    enum
    {
        CARS_ROLLSROYCE
    } CARS;
}
@end

// CARS.m
@implementation BEAUTIFULCARS
+(NSInteger)ROLLSROYCE{ return BEAUTIFULCARS_ROLLSROYCE; }
@end
@implementation CARS
+(NSInteger)ROLLSROYCE{ return CARS_ROLLSROYCE; }
@end
```

Your `.m` source is almost the same:

```
#import "CARS.h"

-(void)printEnumvals
{
    NSLog(@"CARS %d BEAUTIFULCARS %d",
                     CARS.ROLLSROYCE,
            BEAUTIFULCARS.ROLLSROYCE);
}
```

Objective-C does not manage scope in the same way that most other OO languages do.  Interfaces define the properties and messages that an object that interface supports, but don't support protection levels like public or private.  When you define an enum in an `@interface`, that enum ends up in global scope.

Comment: @Thomson Comer : this does not work ///// namespace TEST {
 enum TEST {
  ABC,
  DEF
 };
}

Comment: @Thomson Comer : The compiler says "expected '=' "." etc... 'asm' or '_attribute_' before 'TEST'

Comment: @Oliver, you forgot to rename the source file that is including that namespace code to a `.mm` file.  Namespaces are not supported in Objective-C, which are always suffixed with `.m`.  When you use a namespace you have to treat it as C++ code, which requires that the source file be suffixed `.mm`.

Comment: @Thomson Comer : I did it. It's renamed .mm What else ?

Comment: @Oliver, as far as I can tell this is a stale object (.o) file problem.  I suggest you try cleaning your build products with Build->Clean and trying again.  Also check that in your project settings your C/C++ compiler version is GCC 4.2 - I'm not sure that this works with the LLVM compiler.  I'm having no trouble creating an Enums.h file with the above namespaces, then importing it into an Obj-C source file with .mm extension.  Hopefully you just need to clean your project.

Comment: @Thomson Comer : ok, this seems to work (the first solution) but only if put in a .h that does not contain any typedef enum { ... } theEnum;... Why ?

Comment: @Thomson Comer : is it normal that the compiler is not able to autocomplete CARS::.... ?

Comment: @Oliver : Yes typedef enum { ... } theEnum; is C-style enum while enum theEnum { };  is C++ style enum.  I wouldn't expect the compiler to autocomplete CARS:: since you're essentially asking it to use autocomplete to enumerate all the global variables (but only those in the CARS namespace).

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I didn't want to use C++ namespaces or write redundant Objective-C classes for such a simple case, so I fallen back to the C.

```
// Enum.h
typedef struct 
{
   const int ROLLSROYCE;
} _CARS;

typedef struct 
{
   const int ROLLSROYCE;
} _BEAUTIFULCARS;

extern const _CARS CARS;
extern const _BEAUTIFULCARS BEAUTIFULCARS;
```

And then in Enum.m, define values

```
// Enum.m    

#import "Enum.h"

const _CARS CARS = {0};// 0 is to be assigned to ROLLSROYCE field in struct
const _BEAUTIFULCARS BEAUTIFULCARS = {1}; // same but with 1
```

And finally, in your "main" code

```
#import "Enum.h"

// Some method
{
  NSLog(@"I can refer to CARS.ROLLSROYCE = %d and BEAUTIFULCARS.ROLLSROYCE = %d", CARS.ROLLSROYCE, BEAUTIFULCARS.ROLLSROYCE);
}
```

Which will produce this output:

```
I can refer to CARS.ROLLSROYCE = 0 and BEAUTIFULCARS.ROLLSROYCE = 1
```